# How to Reduce extra black space area In drop Down menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Really Stuck With it .How to Reduce black space area my Drop Down menu . i have Created word press site.its based shopping site.watch and knife site. and Finally created Drop down menu in watch.i have using 5 column .its working perfectly when i remove two column showing black space are. how to reduce it? Looking Like this

I have upload Image What problem i am facing

[image]

I have tired  i cant able to reduce black space area?

My Site Url: http://watchedge.com/

i have used capativa theme? i tired Not Working ?

```
.cap-primary-menu .menu > li.menu-full-width .cap-submenu-ddown {
    padding: 20px 25px 25px;
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #fff;
}


.cap-primary-menu .menu > li.menu-full-width .cap-submenu-ddown .container > ul > li {
    width:30%;
}
```

i have used this css.Not Working ? how to Reduce extra space watch Drop down menu ? when i create drop down menu i am using Css class menu-full-width .. please any idea ? thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like 5 columns to me. Maybe you should try using 3 columns instead?

Comment: i have used   3 columns but extra space showing

Comment: when i create Menu drop down i have used optional css  class menu-full-width

Comment: You could try `width:30%!important`. CSS has a complicated order of preference, and the built in 5 column layout has higher preference than your custom styling. Using `!important` is kinda like using duct tape for repairs. Use it sparingly.